# Cannot link group to a scene

Tags: groups

My scene file is a group of buildings, all linked in from separate files, no problem. but on the new building I am working on, I have selected all objects and grouped them,as before, but when I go to link the group into the main scene, I have no group option. (In the building file the group is shown in outliner). Can anybody help please?

Comment: Not enough information to be able to help you. Could you post your blend file so we can have a look?

Comment: Use this link to post a blend file and pass the link edit in your original post http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score -1):

I think I have cracked it! The file I was trying to link in to had some existing objects selected, so I pressed A to deselect, and my grouped file showed up. Magic.